# Best way to configure Eclipse to work with Maven projects and Java modules

Tags: eclipse, maven

What's the best way to use current Eclipse version (2020.12) + traditional Maven projects (like maven-archetype-quickstart) with main and test sources in the same project + Java (9+) modules? To be more exact, how to configure junit test dependencies so that Eclipse does not show compilation errors.

I'd appreciate if maven-archetype-quickstart with `module-info.java` and Eclipse configuration could be attached too.

Comment: What are your exact compilation errors? [Dependencies have a `<scope>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#dependencies). One of them is „_**test** - this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases. It is not transitive._“.

Comment: Do you have a `modules-info.java` in `src/main/java` and in `src/test/java`?

Comment: @khmarbaise `module-info.java` is not allowed to appear in both places

Comment: Just wanted to know you are on the right path. Second you seemed to be using JUnit 4 which is not not really module as far as I know .. JUnit JUpiter has correct modules... ? Furthermore you are using the eclipse maven plugin? Long time deprecated don't use it anymore ... just import project via Eclipse directly...

Comment: I use m2e, not maven-eclipse-plugin, if you have it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. After adding `module-info.java`, error appears:
[image]

Build path configuration remains:
[image]

"Update Maven Project" has to be executed in Eclipse. Then Eclipse's Maven plugin updates `.classpath` by removing `<attribute name="module" value="true"/>` from

```
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-11">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

which results in this "Java Build Path" in the UI:

[image]